# ASP.NET ScriptManager EnableCdn="True" only works for WebResources.axd, but not for ScriptResources.axd

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

I have .NET 4.5 installed and I checked all libraries. Everything seems fine. But for some reason I don't get the CDN files for the ScriptResources.

[image]

As you can see on the picture, it only works partly. I deinstalled the AjaxControlToolkit a while back. Could this be a reason? This works on my coworkers PC which has the same project and the same configuration (kinda, obviously). But we can't find the difference.

Comment: I commented on your last one, haha. But have you found the files that are missing? I have opened the folder where the files are located and dropped them into the solution. This fixed my issues. I did also have to re-install AjaxControlToolkit as well.

Comment: I'm trying not to use AjaxControlToolkit anymore. And no, didn't find the files, but I rather would fix my setup...
What I did, was just hardcode the cdn path of the files. That works, but it's not pretty...

Comment: *Found the files from his project folder* is what I mean to say in my first comment. Did he uninstall AjaxControlToolkit as well? Have you checked all the references? I would make a copy of each project folder on yours and your co-workers, and then try to open your co-workers.

Comment: He never really had it installed, expect via Nuget. Ok, we did actually find the files on his HD, but I was hoping that I don't have to manually reference them.

Comment: Did this fix your problem? If you did any type of updating or uninstalling, there is a chance that those files became corrupt. This problem happened to me when I updated my jQuery library, my javascript files then became corrupted.

Comment: I think the problem is still that somewhere there is a wrong configuration. The question is why is the scriptmanager loading the wrong files?
Hardcoding the path in the cdn did solve the problem, but it's a hack.

Answer (score 0):

It's about AjaxControlToolkit version. I uninstalled AjaxControlToolkit v16.1.1 and installed v15.1.4, the problem is fixed.